# Create a list of a class and access it from another class

Tags: python, list, class, attributes

What I need to solve is:

```
Create class "Scores" and "Player". 
Class score should have attributes level, score, time. 
Class player should have as information a name and a list of Scores, 
In class player implement the method maxLevel(), 
    which returns the max level achieved by the player.
```

I feel like this is somewhat really easy but I still can't figure it out.

1. How can I make a list of scores exactly?
2. Once the above is done, how do I access the list of scores for each player?

Thanks!

I tried this but I just know im doing things the wrong way.

```
class Score():
    level = 0
    score = 0
    time = 0

    def __init__(self,level,score,time):
        Score.level = level
        score.score = score
        Score.time = time

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores
    def maxLevel():
        ##Do stuff to calculate the max


John = Player("John", [Score(100,1456,50), Score(210,1490,100)])


John.maxLevel()
```

Comment: Please show what you've researched, and what you've tried.

Comment: Edited, it must be awful, I'm a true beginner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating classes that stand for one object and not a list of them. I would change the name of the class "Scores" to "Score" and then I would make as many score objects as I want. Then I could create a list called scores. Now append each score object into the scores list. Now to access the scores of each player type Player.scores, that will display the entire list, Players.scores[1] would pick the second element in the list.

```
class Score(object):
    level = 0
    score = 0
    time = 0

    def __init__(self,level,score,time):
        self.level = level
        self.score = score
        self.time = time

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores

    def maxLevel(self):
        max_level = 0
        for score in self.scores:
            if score.level > max_level:
                max_level = score.level

        return max_level

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jon = Player("John", [Score(100,1456,50), Score(210,1490,100)])
    # Player Name
    print "Name:", jon.name
    # Score Objects
    print "Score Objects:", jon.scores
    # Score Level of 1st score
    print "Score Level 1st Score:", jon.scores[0].level
    # Score Level of 2nd score
    print "Score level 2nd Score:", jon.scores[1].level

    # Max Level info
    max_level = jon.maxLevel()
    print "Max-Level:", max_level
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the reply. Would it be too much to ask if you could explain that with some code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you have defined the `level, score, time` as static class variables.

```
class Score():
    #level = 0  "these should not be here"
    #score = 0
    #time = 0

    def __init__(self,level,score,time):
        #you are not defining them for a class, but for a class instance, so each individual instance of the object score
        self.level = level  
        self.score = score
        self.time = time

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores
    def maxLevel():
        ##Do stuff to calculate the max


John = Player("John", [Score(100,1456,50), Score(210,1490,100)])


John.maxLevel()
```

Also, if the score class, is not having any other attributes or special methods, consider using the [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) class. It serves a simple purpose better.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Score = namedtuple('Score', ['level', 'score', 'time'])
```